# Difference between signed and unsigned data types?

Tags: c, unsigned

```
main()
{
    char i=255;
    printf("\n%x\n",i);
}
```

output:`ffffffff`

```
main()
{
    u_char i=255;
    printf("\n%x\n",i);
}
```

output:`ff`

What is happening here? Kindly explain the output to me with some good links. This is a very basic thing I guess and I am getting really confused...

Answer (score 10):

What you are seeing here is caused by two things:

- `255` does not fit in the range of `char` (note that it is implementation-defined whether `char` is equivalent to `signed char` or `unsigned char`, but evidently on your platform it is `signed char`).  The resulting behaviour is implementation-defined, but typically it will wrap round and become -1; see [*two's complement*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).
- [*integer promotion*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Type_promotion_in_C-like_languages), because `printf()` is a [variable-argument function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vararg).  Integral-type arguments (like `char`) are automatically promoted to `int`.

So `printf()` sees an `int` with a value of `-1`, and prints its hexadecimal representation accordingly.

For the `unsigned` case, there is no wrap-around.  `printf()` sees an `int` with a value of `255`, and prints its hexadecimal representation accordingly (omitting the leading zeros).

Comment: Could you throw some more light on that please? Why is it getting promoted? 255 is 11111111 in binary, so 2's comp will be 000000001. So should it not print 0f?

Comment: @Naman: It is getting promoted because that is what the C standard says should happen.  When I say "two's complement", I mean "two's complement arithmetic", not "the two's complement of the value".

Answer (score 4):

The C compiler has to expand the value passed to `printf` (this is called "promotion"), because `printf` is a variadic function (it can be called with differing arguments). For values of type `char`, the promoted value is of type `int`. Since your compiler's `char` type seems to be signed, the promoted value is sign extended. In binary:

```
char i = 255           // or: 11111111 in binary
int promoted_i = -1    // or: 11....11111 (usually, 32 or 64 ones)
```

In the unsigned case, no sign-extension happens:

```
char u = 255           // or: 11111111 in binary, same as above but with different interpretation
unsigned int pu = i    // or: 00....0011111111 (8 ones, preceded by the appropriate number of zeroes)
```

Answer (score 0):

`char i = 255;` invokes implementation-defined behavior by converting a value to a signed type into which it does not fit (assuming `char` is only 8 bits and plain `char` is signed, both of which are also implementation-specific.

Answer (score 0):

When you set an 8-bit signed variable to the value 255, which it can't hold, it seems in this case it sets the negative (high-end) flag to 1, so the value would be -1 if it were signed, but then it gets converted to an integer -1 which is `ffffffff`.